# Rails installation error - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

I seem to have a conflict when trying to install Rails on Mountain Lion. I have tried updating Ruby but this did not help. I also tried Rails Installer but that also gave an error. Ruby version is 1.8.7

Here is the error I am getting from terminal

```
sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Brother, let me tell you: This could take quite a bit of googling. I just went thru similar hell this past week (I'm a first time user of RoR on OSX). If you haven't already go get [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and [RVM](https://rvm.io/). Go from there.

Comment: I'm a first timer too and man was it a convoluted process. I finally got it working with RVM. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/

Although by no means was this a walk in the park, due to version conflicts, the tut is over a year old and Rails now requires at least Ruby 1.9.3 and you need to install Command Line tools in Xcode. This tut uses RVM.

I tried Rails Installer which sounds a lot easier than doing it this way but that also gave me an error. I think I had major version conflicts going on. If you are trying to install Rails then I'd try Rails Installer first. Here's a very recent tut on installing it, http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues and I had all the requirements.  My solution?  Upgraded (through RVM) my version of Ruby from 2.0.0-p195 to 2.0.0-p353.  After this I tried `gem install rails` and it worked like it was supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the x-code command line tools and then the rails install worked correctly.

Comment: I re-ran ***xcode-select --install*** and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use RailsInstaller and [these step-by-step instructions](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/osx_railsinstaller?back=macintosh#step2-1-1):

Comment: Thanks I tried using rails installer but it flat out wouldn't install. I managed to eventually get it working through RVM.